# split in android is not working good

Tags: java, android, eclipse, split

i have this string

```
"ok[separador]2272[dato]HOSPITAL ISSSTE 2             [dato]Ok, Realizado correctamente[fila]48612[dato]CFE YUCALPETEN[dato]Ok, Realizado correctamente[fila]48687[dato]IMPRESOS PUBLICITARIOS[dato]Ok, Realizado correctamente[fila]"
```

first step i need to have 2 string split by [separador] so i need get these 2 string:

```
ok
2272[dato]HOSPITAL ISSSTE 2             [dato]Ok, Realizado correctamente[fila]48612[dato]CFE YUCALPETEN[dato]Ok, Realizado correctamente[fila]48687[dato]IMPRESOS PUBLICITARIOS[dato]Ok, Realizado correctamente[fila]
```

then in my code i have this:

```
String[] arregloresultado=resultado.split("[separador]");
```

but i get an array with these values

```
[", k[, , , , , , , , , ]2272[, , t, ]HOSPITAL ISSSTE 2             [, , t, ]Ok, R, , liz, , ,  c, , , , ct, m, nt, [fil, ]48612[, , t, ]CFE YUCALPETEN[, , t, ]Ok, R, , liz, , ,  c, , , , ct, m, nt, [fil, ]48687[, , t, ]IMPRESOS PUBLICITARIOS[, , t, ]Ok, R, , liz, , ,  c, , , , ct, m, nt, [fil, ]"]
```

how can i get the result i want? i would like this was not a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[separador]` contains special characters for regexes. You'll split on s, e, p, a, r, d, *AND* o. Use:

```
String[] arregloresultado=resultado.split("\\[separador\\]");
```

The regex uses one backslash but Java literals require a backslash for the backslash hence 2 backslashes.

Comment: i have try it now, that you said but this does not work  resultado.split("\\[separador\\]") and this does not work too resultado.split("\[separador\]")

Comment: @angel Use 2 backslashes for each bracket.

Comment: hehe i used two backslashed but stackoverflow delete one

Comment: invalid scape sequence(valid one are \b \t \n \f \r" \' \\)

Comment: Again, put in 2 backslashes in. This errorshould only show up if you only put one in. Put it in like it's written in my post.

Comment: i copy and paste your post and this did not work i used 3 backslashes and this works

Comment: as you told work but if i do it on Watch i need put 3 backslashes and i was checking in Watch

Comment: Um? OK? I've personally needed 2. Are you using some sort of IDE?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35526/discussion-between-hexafraction-and-angel)

Answer (score 1):

You're separator contains regex metacharacters. To avoid this kind of mistake you can escape them manually (hexafraction's answer), or let the escaping be done for you like this:

```
String[] arregloresultado = resultado.split(Pattern.quote("[separador]"));
```